# Eclipse hangs when debugging android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am running Eclipse Juno on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit with the ADT Plugin. I am working on an app for android and I can develop just fine, but whenever my app throws an uncaught exception while debugging, eclipse freezes and I have to force quit the program and restart again. This makes determining the bugs in my app near impossible because I can't even get the stack trace for the exception.

EDIT:
It seems to work sometimes, and I have noticed not discernible pattern as to when eclipse hangs.

Comment: Not sure about your specific eclipse problem, but you should be able to see the stack trace for all of your errors using Logcat, whether you're debugging or not.

Comment: HAve you determined if it's just your application or all applications?  Try making a new very basic project and see if you can debug that one.

Comment: It appears to be all applications. Also, now it's starting to hang simply by plugging my phone in.

Comment: Any one able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Change the preferences of Android->LOgcat->Max number of logcat messages to buffer to '5000'. That should solve the problem.

[Update] You can also hit the [x] clear button on the logcat to clear all recent logcat messages.

Good luck!

Comment: I think you might on to something! I had default of 5000, bumped it up to 20.000 as LogCat was spammed with debug statements from Android and it seems to work now. I don't know if it's coincidence, but sometimes the GL log statements don't seem to always occur...

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem when trying to debug on a windows 8 workstation and the regular Android ADT bundle. I solved it by NOT using the standard ADT bundle. Instead I downloaded the latest eclipse (4.3.1/Kepler) and installed the SDK and eclipse plugin manually using the instructions from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html called "Setting up an Existing IDE".

So at least is my case the problem seemed to be Eclipse Juno version. When moving to Eclipse Kepler it worked.